# Flask upload file with AJAX and button submit not working

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, flask

I've trying to implement a file upload (a `.csv`) with bootstrap, and submit it using a button.

I've tried alot of different ways of implementing the file upload and so far none of them work, I can't seem to pin point the issue:

```html
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="excel-upload" name="file">
      <div class="file-upload-wrapper">
               <label for="file">Upload Excel DAT File</label>
                     <input type="file" name="excel-upload-file" class="form-control-file" id="excel-upload-file">
                         <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="button" id="submit_table" method="POST" style="margin-top: 30px">
                     <span class="spinner-border spinner-border-sm" role="status" aria-hidden="true" id = "loading_spinner_table"></span>
                                        Submit File
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </form>
```

```js
$("#submit_table").on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#loading_spinner_table").show();
        let form_data = new FormData($('#excel-upload-file')[0]);
        console.log(form_data);
        $.ajax({
            url: "/upload_excel",
            type: "POST",
            data: form_data,
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data)
                $("#loading_spinner_table").hide();
                Plotly.plot('table_data',data);
            },
            error: function(result) {
                $("#loading_spinner_table").hide();
                alert("Invalid Submission / No Data");
            }
        });
    });
```

```py
@app.route('/upload_excel', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def upload_blob():
    if request.method in ('POST','GET'):
        print(request.files)
        if 'file' not in request.files:
            print('NO FILE')
            flash('No file part')
            return redirect(request.url)
        file = request.files['file']
        if file.filename == '':
            print('NOTHING SELECTED')
            flash('No file selected for uploading')
            return redirect(request.url)
        if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
            filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
    """ Additional processing"""
```

Answer (score 1):

We had same issue in MVC we changed button to **input type **submit**** then it worked.
Button doesn't work work for form submit

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple changes that need to be made.

The FormData API needs to take a form, not a form element. Change the line where you build that object to this: `let form_data = new FormData($('#excel-upload')[0]);`

Next, your ajax call needs to specify that you're using multipart form encoding. Add this parameter to the call: `enctype: 'multipart/form-data'`

Third, the key for the file you want to use server side will match the name of the form element. In this case, you want to look for `request.files['excel_upload_file']`

It looks like this code is pulled from the [flask file upload tutorial](http://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.0.x/patterns/fileuploads/), so I'll assume you've set up flask to handle uploads already.

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately after implementing these changes, the `request.files` dictionary is empty

Comment: Looks like I forgot to change the id when building the form data object. It should be pointing to the overall form (#excel-data), not to the file (#excel-data-file)